# Ansible conditionals with when

Tags: ansible

Confused with Ansible why this is occurring. It appears that booleans aren't working correctly without being very explicit. I'm not aware of any other way to set_fact without using the Jinja2 syntax which feels like it might be the culprit. Can anyone shed light on it?

```
 - hosts: 127.0.0.1
   connection: local
   tasks:
    - set_fact:
        im_defined: "something"
        im_false: "{{1 == 2}}"

    - name: this should be skipped
      debug: msg="SHOULD NOT SEE THIS MESSAGE! im_defined={{im_defined}} im_false={{im_false}}"
      when: im_defined is defined and im_false
```

---

```
> ansible-playbook ansible-test.yml

PLAY [127.0.0.1] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [set_fact ] *************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [this should be skipped] ************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "SHOULD NOT SEE THIS MESSAGE! im_defined=something im_false=False"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

It appears that if I change the *when* to read:

```
when: im_defined is defined and im_false == True
```

It works as expected:

```
TASK: [this should be skipped] ************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind this is, your fact `im_false` actually is a string, not a boolean.

I tested a bit and `im_false == True` and `im_false == False` have the same outcome here, so I guess it really checks if it IS True and not Truthy.

The correct way to check is with a conversion filter:

```
when: im_defined is defined and im_false|bool
```

Also see [this bug report](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5392).

Comment: Awesome, I was thinking it might be something like this but I couldn't put my finger on it. Wish there was a way to evaluate variables besides the jinja2 stuff and we wouldn't get strings popping out.... sigh